# Как запретить доступ к файловой системе TeX live компилятору

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, latex

Есть сервер на Node Js, который с помощью командной строки запускает TeX Live компилятор. Так как код для компиляции задают пользователи, существует возможность читать и редактировать файлы на сервере с помощью возможностей самого LaTeX-а, а это не очень приятно. Но, к сожалению, полностью ограничивать доступ нельзя, хотя бы потому что компилятор должен сгенерировать финальный файл. Какие способы ограничить возможности на один каталог/пространство существуют? Желательно способ попроще.

Comment: ручками через chroot или что-то готовое вроде freejail

Answer (score 3):

Техник для Sandboxing-а несколько, основные

Контейнеры: chroot, docker, lxc(в режиме виртуализации приложения)

Неймспэйсы: через unshare, freejail

Контроль доступа через: AppArmor или SeLinux

Способ попроще - настроить freejail c noroot и overlay и удалить из overlay все что не требуется для tex.